# How many time workflow gets rescheduled if error happens?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, designer-workflow, 2016

I am setting workflow start on creation.
It shows error and keep retrying every 17 minutes.

But **I want to know how many times or how much hours this retrying happens?**

Please let me know if anyone knows.

Answer (score 0):

The timer job used to process the SharePoint workflows will continue to try and run the workflow until you stop it.  The WorkFlowTimerJob runs every 5 minutes and has a 15 workflow limit per timer job if I remember correctly.  In order to stop your workflow from running, you need to go to the workflow property on the list and stop it or it will just keep trying to run it.  It can also start to stack the workflow processes and can cause performance issues and eventually critical issues at the Farm level.

Comment: In my case, workflow automatically suspended after 9 hrs. Is there any limit for reschedule? up to this times or hours?

Comment: I do not think so, now on an Azure platform, I cannot give you a good answer because I am not sure if timerjobs are different in a cloud SharePoint farm.  I would have your server admins look at the timerjob schedule.  I do not think there is a limit on how many tries.  It will keep going and trying to run until terminated.